# Why can't I declare an array of functions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I'm used to declaring array inline like this:

```
    String s1 = "world";
    String[] strings = { "world" };
```

Why can't I do the same for functions?  Given I have a class `Book` with `getTitle()` and `getAuthor()` methods, this is valid:

```
    Function<Book, String> f1 = Book::getTitle;
    System.out.println(f1.apply(myBook));
```

However this is not:

```
    Function<Book, String>[] funcs = { Book::getTitle, Book::getAuthor };
    for (Function<Book, String> f2 : funcs) {
        System.out.println(f2.apply(myBook));
    }
```

It doesn't like the inline array declaration and the compiler error is "Cannot create a generic array of Function"

**Edit**
I'd argue my question isn't a duplicate of the suggestion as I want to statically define a set of functions using the array initializer syntax

Comment: Try with a map, like this `Map<String, Function<Book, String>> mapToFunctions = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: If is a generic type, you need to use `funcs = new Function<Book, String>[] { Book::getTitle };`

Comment: @Héctor that gives the same error

Comment: `Function[] funcs = { (Function<Book, String >) Book::getTitle };`.

Comment: If you want to simply apply the same method call to all of your books(assuming books is a List), you can simply do `List<String> titles = books.stream().map(Book::getTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());` and then `titles.stream().forEach(System.out::println);` to print them. It is redundant to create an array of the same function.

Comment: @ichantz my example is greatly simplified; in reality I want to statically define many functions in an array or list and invoke them in turn on multiple instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public static void testFunction() {
    Map<String, Function<Book, String>> mapToFunctions = new HashMap<>();

    Function<Book, String> myFunction = x -> new String(x.getTitle());

    mapToFunctions.put("firstfunction", myFunction);

    for (Function<Book, String> f : mapToFunctions.values()) {
        System.out.println(f.apply(new Book("my title")));
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Using `Set<Function<Book, String>>` it would be something like:

```
package com.victor.main;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionalTest {
    public static void testFunction() {
        Set<Function<Book, String>> mapToFunctions = new HashSet<>();

        Function<Book, String> myFunction = x -> new String(x.getTitle());

        mapToFunctions.add(myFunction);

        for (Function<Book, String> f : mapToFunctions) {
            System.out.println(f.apply(new Book("my title")));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will get difficult to maintain when there are many functions, as you have to give them a name and a lambda.  I really want a simple list.

Comment: Try with a `Set<Function<Book, String>> funSet = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: I updated the answer with a version using `Set<Function<Book, String>>`

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this falls into the category of "not possible because of type erasure"